# Does rexray support multi host volume mounts?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-volume, docker-swarm-mode

I want to share a volume across multiple containers , in docker swarm .
I need it to be such that all the containers have R/W access to this volume at any point of time .
If not rexray ,is there any other docker volume plugin which would enable me to do the same thing ?

The rexray documentation doesn't state the fact clearly.

Comment: There is also Infinit (aquired by Docker): https://infinit.sh/

Answer (score 1):

REX-Ray has to use some backend storage driver. This is more about the storage, which has to support multiple read/write connections to the same volume. If you truly need multiple read/write, some options include:

[REX-Ray with AWS EFS driver](http://rexray.readthedocs.io/en/v0.10.0/user-guide/storage-providers/#elastic-file-system). EFS supports multiple NFS r/w connections.

https://portworx.com which will replicate data between nodes.

[REX-Ray with any custom NFS storage](https://rexray.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/schedulers/docker/plug-ins/csi-nfs/).

Maybe a custom storage solution with drivers [from Docker Store](https://store.docker.com/search?category=volume&q=&type=plugin).